# Ubuntu 20.04 keyboard (but not the mouse) freeze

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, freeze

since upgrading from linux-image-5.11.0-46-generic to linux-image-5.13.0-25-generic (and higher) I occasionally experience keyboard freezes on my laptop.

- Un- and re plugging in the external keyboard or even a different brand of external keyboard does not help.
- The internal keyboard on the laptop freezes too(!)
- Caps- and numlock stop functioning.
- The external usb mouse keeps working, though only for moving, not clicking etc.
- Logging in through the network still works.

Downgrading to the 5.11 kernel is not an option since the disk is encrypted and upgrading made the 5.11 incompatible with the encryption.

Anyone with bright ideas, besides waiting for the Jellyfish ;-) ?